# Не удается подключить библиотеку MySql

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, mysqlconnector

Пытаюсь скомпилировать простейшую программу с использованием MySql Connector:[Running Simple Query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-query.html) с помощью MinGW. Компиляция проходит успешно, а в процессе линковки вылезает ошибка `undefined reference to _imp___ZN3sql5mysql19get_driver_instanceEv`, либо `undefined reference to get_driver_instance()`. Параметры линковщика: `-LC:/lib/mysql/lib -lmysqlcppconn-static`. В папке C:/lib/mysql/lib находятся файлы библиотеки mysqlcppconn.dll/.lib и mysqlcppconn-static.lib, скачанные с того же сайта. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Ну, для начала, имя `mysqlcppconn-static.lib` - это библиотека для MS VS, а не для gcc/g++. Параметр `-lmysqlcppconn-static` означает, что линкер MinGW будет искать файл с именем `libmysqlcppconn-static.a`. Можно попробовать подсунуть эту библиотеку переименовав в ту, которая ожидается или просто как объектный файл с абсолютным путем (без указания опции -l), но думаю, на этом проблемы не закончатся. У этих коннекторов есть плохая особенность - они завязаны на конкретную версию Visual Studio.. В общем, можно попробовать собрать коннектор самому в MinGW. И взять коннектор от MariaDB, а не MySQL.

Comment: @Vladimir а MS VS умеет линковать .a файлы? На тот случай, если придется менять компилятор.

Comment: Честно говоря, я не пробовал. Я не люблю MS VS и почти не имею с ним дел. Но я подозреваю, что под Windows формат библиотек .a (от mingw) и .lib не отличаются ничем, кроме имени. Предположение основываю на том, что библиотеки .lib mingw обычно ел без проблем (я когда-то баловался на библиотеках BLAS/LAPACK). Ну а если я не прав, тогда может кто из сообщества пояснит.

Comment: В общем случае, форматы библиотек для VS и MinGW не совместимы. Более того, даже .a  (или .lib) библиотеки разных версий компиляторов могут быть несовместимы между собой. [Interoperability of Libraries Created by Different Compiler Brands](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Interoperability_of_Libraries_Created_by_Different_Compiler_Brands)

Comment: Я скачал эту библиотеку в формате .a, но ошибки никуда не делись.

Comment: @zed, да, Вы правы. Я не учел, что в то время все сборки mingw использовали модель исключений SJLJ (совместимую с VS) и библиотеки были написаны на фортране. А там, как и у Си, нет декорирования имен. Наверное поэтому и не встретил проблем тогда.

Comment: @ИгорьМахов, я не знаю где вы умудрились стащить готовую .a библиотеку, но подозреваю, что она из linux - и тогда ничего и не должно было выйти. Лучше всего, Вам будет самому собрать своим компилятором этот коннектор. Но тут есть тоже подстава: у меня без проблем получилось собрать и использовать только коннекторы версий 2.0.0 и 2.1.0 (возможно, я просто не знаю как бороться с более новыми). И из самого последнего, что я нашел, это пропатченную версию 2.3.1 от арчероводов: https://github.com/Martchus/mariadb-connector-c/tree/v2.3.1-mingw-w64 - она у меня тоже работает нормально (с mingw-w64).